# SAML SSO WITH ADFS IN C#

Tags: saml, adfs

> in my project.i need to implement SAML SSO with ADFS in c#
>
> i have .cer and .pfx files

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a SAML client-side stack.

Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).